# python: creating dummy variables per date

Tags: pandas, dummy-variable

I have the following dataframe:

```
id start_date end_date value 
1  2010       2014     A
2  2010       2013     C
3  2012       2013     D
```

and I want to create new variables with the year and the value in it:

```
id 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
1  A    A    A    A    A
2  C    C    C    C    Na
3  Na   Na   D    D    Na
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create `range` by list comprehension, then use [`DataFrame.explode`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['y'] = [range(s, e+1) for s, e in zip(df['start_date'], df['end_date'])]
df = df.explode('y').pivot('id','y','value')
print (df)
y  2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
id                         
1     A    A    A    A    A
2     C    C    C    C  NaN
3   NaN  NaN    D    D  NaN
```

If performance is important use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) with [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['end_date'].sub(df['start_date']).add(1))]
df['y'] = df['start_date'].add(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount())

df = df.pivot('id','y','value')
print (df)
y  2010 2011 2012 2013 2014
id                         
1     A    A    A    A    A
2     C    C    C    C  NaN
3   NaN  NaN    D    D  NaN
```